# Can't resolve 'fs' or 'path' Edge-js and Angular

Tags: c#, angular, electron, edgejs

I am making an Electron Angular app using electron-edge-js to avoid having to run a server to transition between angular and C# code. The app works as long as I don't actually call edge to do anything, but fails  (at build) with:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' (or 'path') in ... node_modules\electron-edge-js\lib.`

I have tried every solution I can find online. I used angular-builders\custom-webpack and was able to get the application to build, but the next error I got was 'require is not defined'.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/pdpete/AngularElectronEdgeQuickstart

In app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Edge from 'electron-edge-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'The Wrong App Name';

  // if this is commented out, the app works fine, but with 'The Wrong App Name'
  constructor() {
    var getAppName = Edge.func({
      assemblyFile: "Controller.dll",
      typeName: "Controller.NameController",
      methodName: "GetName"
    });

    getAppName(null, function (error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
      this.title = result;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, after a bunch of research, Angular 5 and above do not allow access to fs (or other node modules), so it is impossible to write an Edge app with an Angular version > 5.